# How can i highlight a cell with pandas in python, based on the value of another cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these columns

[image]

How can I create a condition that if the word 'zero' is in column 'Code', it then checks if the value in column '% VAT Rate verification' is 0, and if it is, it highlights it green, if it`s not, it makes it red?

Comment: i am currently developing a script with python that takes a df from an excel file, and creates another excel that should higlight some cells based on some conditions

Comment: i am talking about the pandas df.style.apply() function and the conditions i have to set